# Call function in unmanaged DLL from C# with custom parameter

Tags: c#, c++

I've been trying to call from my C# application, a function in a C++ dll. This is what I have so far, but I don't know if I am on the right way or if I am doing something wrong. Since the function parameter is of custom type, I don't know how to proceed.

This is the function definition in C++

```
int GetDeviceList(
PRINTER_LIST* pList
);
```

and these are the parameters

```
#define MAX_PRINTER 32
typedef struct {
    WCHAR   name[128];          // printer name
    WCHAR   id[64];             // printer ID
    WCHAR   dev[64];            // device connection
    WCHAR   desc[256];          // description
    int     pid;                // USB product ID
} PRINTER_ITEM;

typedef struct  {
    int                 n;
    PRINTER_ITEM    item[MAX_PRINTER];
} PRINTER_LIST;
```

So far I was able to convert the parameters

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct PrinterItem {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 128)]
        public string name;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 64)]
        public string id;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 64)]
        public string dev;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 256)]
        public string desc;

        public int pid;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct PrinterList {
        public int n;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 32)]
        public PrinterItem[] item;
    }
```

and I have been trying to implement it into my program

```
public
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("dllName.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern int GetDeviceList(_____);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var deviceList = GetDeviceList(____);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your intent is to pass a single `PrinterList` by reference.

```cs
public
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("dllName.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern int GetDeviceList(ref PrinterList list);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PrinterList list = new PrinterList();
            var deviceList = GetDeviceList(ref list);
        }
    }
```

Ensure that unmanaged dll uses `Standard call` invocation (your C declaration doesn't state it).

It should work.

Comment: Your second bullet is guaranteed because the function receives the pointer by copy -- it would have no way to communicate a pointer to newly allocated memory back to the caller.

Comment: You are right, because `PrinterList` is defined as `struct` (not as `class`).

Comment: There's no difference in C++, which is the part that can't change.

Comment: I'm talking about c# part. The only reason why we have a copy of the pointer...

Comment: There's a copy of the pointer because the C++ function signature has a pass-by-value parameter of pointer type.  `int GetDeviceList( ` **`PRINTER_LIST* pList`** `);`  Pass-by-value always results in a copy.  There doesn't exist any C# code that could call this function without making a copy of a pointer.

Comment: Anyway @Ben Voigt you are right. For both reasons (C++ side and C#). I'll remove last bullet.